# Lazy load require statement within function call?

Tags: javascript

I need to refactor the following to lazy load `LargeImport`:

```
const LargeImport = require('large-import');
const useLargeImport = new LargeImport();

const MyModule = {
    init: function(){
        if(something) {
            this.fire()
        } else {
            this.fire2()
        }
    },
    fire: function(){
        useLargeImport.doSomething();

    },
    fire2: function(){
        useLargeImport.doSomethingElse();
    }
}

module.exports = MyModule;
```

How can I only load download LargeImport on the client once `fire` or `fire2` are executed?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of asynchronous `import` on any native event. Remember to add keyword `async` on beginning of function

```
 <button
    onClick={async () => {
      await import("./child.js");
    }}
  >
    click
 </button>
```

Your code can be updated as

```
fire: async function(){
 useLargeImport.doSomething();
 await import("./child.js");
},
```

Demo codesandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-browser-tnrtj